# C++ passing std::shared_ptr<RECT> through function

Tags: c++, rect

```
void PlayerHealthBar::SetSourceRect(std::shared_ptr<RECT> sourceRect)
{
    this->sourceRect = sourceRect;
}
```

.CPP file I am trying to set the source rect from

```
playerHealthBar->SetSourceRect(std::shared_ptr<RECT>(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
```

The error is on  the .cpp file on `shared_ptr<RECT>` saying:

```
8   IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "std::shared_ptr<_Ty>::shared_ptr [with _Ty=RECT]" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (double, double, double, double)    ...\Ship.cpp    84
```

I am not sure what this means. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide a dynamically allocated pointer to [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)'s constructor. Alternatively, you can also, and I'd recommend it, use the "factory function" [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared), as follows:

```
playerHealthBar->SetSourceRect(std::make_shared<RECT>(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
//                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Of course assuming `RECT` accepts 4 double-literal-convertible types in one of its constructors.